# Any other way to play background music in iOS game development?

Tags: objective-c, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem right now. I develop game application for iPad with cocos2d. In my application, I use background music. When I use cocos2d music method SimpleAudioEngine, i got leak. However, my bos don't want have a leak in our application. Any other way to play background music except using SimpleAudioEngine and not get a leak?

Thanx before. Regards.

Comment: Could you not just use AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: Any other way to set music in iOS rather than use AVAudioPlayer?

Answer (score 2):

How do you know that you have a leak? Often times what is reported as a leak truly isn't a leak, or a leak in your own code. In particular the static analyzer only makes suggestions but is quite often wrong about his assumptions.

You may also want to contact the library author Steve Oldmeadow, he can be found on the cocos2d forum. At least he may be able to confirm a bug, or explain why it's not a leak.

Secondly, I wouldn't put too much weight on the leaks. Let's assume you're leaking 16 Bytes every time you start a music. You would have to start the music 16.000 times to have leaked 16 KB. How likely is this in your app, and how badly do you "need" those 16 KB?

Third, tell your boss you fixed the leak. If he doesn't want leaks in the app, he's obviously not a (good) programmer. I know it's a lie, and I know there's going to be programmers who'll hate me. But really before you spend hours or even days to find a "better" way of playing music (possibly with other side effects) rather than using what's tried and true in hundreds of iPhone apps, such a white lie is going to save your boss a bunch of money.

I think that too many people think that leaking memory equals an app that crashes often. Such is not the case, unless the leaks are significant, resulting in out of memory errors or in some scenarios memory fragmentation.

Comment: The leak in question is quite substantial, 512 bytes each time if I remember correctly. I've never managed to find out exactly what's causing it, but it's also never been a problem worth spending too long on a solution for.

Also, the static analyzer has never detected it, I've only ever seen it on the Leaks tool.

In short, I agree with this answer, but I'd suggest explaining to your boss that the leak is in code that you can't change without causing more problems for yourself.

Comment: You're right, if the leak is this substantial and it's occuring to all users and every time, it should be reported as a bug in CocosDenshion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SoundMaster](https://github.com/jerminal/SoundMaster) engine instead of *CocosDension Sound Engine*. **ARC** support, **memory management (NO LEAKS)** and many other features like **fade in/out**, **relative volumes** for effects or **cross-fades**.